# Magento sql query from phtml

Tags: mysql, magento, magento-1.7, php

I wanted to know how to run sql queries in magento via the phtml files. The query itself is quite complicated and will require joins. Any ideas?

For you information:

I have products which have 3 custom attributes( Towns, Regions, Cities).
Now what I am trying to achieve is a list of towns from A-Z in an alphabet order. When clicked on this town, it filters the product associated with the town.

Hope it makes sense.

Any help is much appreciated.

Julian

Comment: Is your intention to have this as part of the left Layered Navigation on category/search pages, or is this used to filter in some other context?

Comment: Please don't do this, i've had to fix many bad examples of coding like this.

Comment: Yes, I have found the Magento way of calling queries via the Model. Thank  you for all the help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The phtml file is technically nothing else than a usual php file, so you can use all models, ressources and so on. So you could just go with:

```
$resource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource'); 
$readConnection = $resource->getConnection('core_read'); 
$query = 'SELECT * FROM ' . $resource->getTableName('catalog/product');
$results = $readConnection->fetchAll($query);
```

**BUT the phtml file is a view, so you should not work directly on database there. Instead try to create a model, use that in the block and then call the prepared data from the block object.**

Comment: **"BUT the phtml file is a view, so you should not work directly on database there. Instead try to create a model, use that in the block and then call the prepared data from the block object."** x 1000.

Comment: Hmm. I don't seem to be having much luck with this. Could you point me in the right direction on how to create a Model and call in the phtml please. Thank you so much for all your help so far.

Comment: There's a really good tutorial on the magento commerce website: http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/magento-for-dev-part-5-magento-models-and-orm-basics